# Is it possible to install on to a mac with no OS currently installed

Tags: system-installation, macbook

I have been given an old Macbook and was asked to wipe and restore the OS. 
I followed the allpe guides but the Macbook is failing to install via the internet recovery service. 
Apple them selfs have said that a physical copy of the OS could get the Macbook running again but its a problem to find a physical copy of old OS.
So i was just wondering if it would be possible to install elementary OS without the Macbook having a working OS on it. 
For some extra infomation i can get to disk utility and the terminal if needed to and i have a windows pc to make the usb drive. 
Thank you for the help

Comment: Keep in mind, many have had issues with wifi on Macs running all types of Linux. Be prepared for a bit of a headache.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible if you have an Intel CPU, you just need

1. [Download the ISO](https://elementary.io/).
2. [Create a bootable USB drive in Windows with Rufus or Etcher](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium).
3. [Inserting your install  USB drive on the MacBook](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#booting-from-the-installation-medium).
4. Start your MacBook.
5. After you hear the chime, press and hold `Option`.
6. Shortly after selecting the appropriate boot drive, you should be presented with the elementary OS splash screen. You may now follow the on-screen instructions which will guide you through the rest of the process.

Ref: [Oficial Install Guide by Elementary OS for Mac](https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#installation).